# Thymeleaf future/past dates

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a database with a timesheet table which has an id column and wcdate(week commencing) column. I have 4 scenarios to accomplish on a web page, using Thymeleaf.

I am new to Thymeleaf, I have looked at Thymeleaf regarding dates, but I flummoxed about how to manipulate a date for instance more than week ago, do something. There are four scenarios which work on timesheet table and wcdate column. I didn't use the `<pre> </pre>` tags because the code didn't show up correctly.

```
<!--if the id is 0 but the wcdate is in the future, show as available-->
        <span th:if="${timesheet.id == 0 AND timesheet.wcdate.after()}"
        class="available">AVAILABLE</span>

        <!--if the timesheet id is 0 and the wcdate is today or in the past, show as missing-->
        <span
        th:unless="${timesheet.id == 0 AND timesheet.wcdate.createNow(),'YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm')}"
        class="missing">MISSING</span>

        <!--if timesheet is 0-->
        <span
        th:unless="${timesheet.id == 0}"
        class="draft">DRAFT</span>

        <!--if the id is not 0 but the wcdate is more than a week ago -->
        <span
        th:unless="${timesheet.id == !0 AND timesheet.wcdate.}"
        class="overdue">OVERDUE</span>
```

Comment: Minor note: `timesheet.id == !0` looks as if it should be `timesheet.id != 0`, where `!=` is the "not equal to" operator - [see here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#standard-expression-syntax).

Comment: Yes it should, thanks Andrew James for pointing that out, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to directly expose an entity to your template, you can expose additional helper variables to make your templates simpler.

I am currently supposing that your controller looks something like this:

```
@GetMapping
public String showTimesheet(Model model) {
  Timesheet timesheet = ... // from service or repo
  model.addAttribute("timesheet", timesheet );
}
```

You can do something like this:

```
@GetMapping
public String showTimesheet(Model model) {
  Timesheet timesheet = ... // from service or repo
  model.addAttribute("timesheet", timesheet );
  model.addAttribute("timesheetStatus", calculateTimesheetStatus(timesheet) );
}
```

And your template becomes:

```
<span th:class="${timesheetStatus}">${timesheetStatus}</span>
```

This way, you can do the calculations in Java.

If the `Timesheet` class has all the info, you can also expose a `getStatus()` method and use something like this for the template:

```
<span th:class="${timesheet.status}">${timesheet.status}</span>
```

Comment: Hi Wim, thank you very much for your answer, very useful. I've checked the Java code, (it's not my code), but what I think they have done is used the java.util.Date, where I can see the timesheet object etc. But they have just gone with manipulating the Thymeleaf local date variables, for instance wcdate, they would want a case for deducting a certain amount of time like days, weeks and months or the reverse adding days, weeks, months and say 'after the wcdate', thanks for your help in my understanding.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean I am afraid.